# Use the zephyr rest api to get test summary results when not in folders

Tags: jira, jira-zephyr

Have been successful in using the rest api to get summary of execution results:

`http://localhost:2990/jira/rest/zapi/latest/cycle/cycleId/folders?projectId=&versionId=&limit=&offset=`
However, the way that my organisation has organised things is to have put most of the data into cycles, without putting them into folders.

e.g.

Version 1

> cycle 1
>
> cycle 2
>
> - folder 2a
> - folder 2b

I can get results for folder 2a/2b etc, but not for cycle 1 as it doesn't have any sub-folders. But I can see the results in jira

[image]

I've done my best to download the data using:

`http://localhost:2990/jira/rest/zapi/latest/cycle?projectId=`

but it's only by downloading each and every execution and the result of it that I'm able to get this data. It'd be very good if I could get the summary for the cycle, just like I can for folders, with a roll up of pass and fail results. Is this possible? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

You can list all executions of a cycle with their statuses using this request:

```
GET http://localhost:2990/jira/rest/zapi/latest/execution?projectId={project_id}&versionId={version_id}&cycleId={cycle_id}
```

It is documented [here](https://getzephyr.docs.apiary.io/#reference/executionresource/get-list-of-execution/get-list-of-execution).